# *Solved Can't get realtek rtl8811cu wifi adapter drivers to work with elementary OS 6.1

Tags: wifi, drivers, hardware

*For some reason when I tried the same thing as before the fresh install it worked this time.
I went here:
https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU
Followed the exact instructions again

```
>sudo su
>mkdir -p ~/build
>cd ~/build
>git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
>sudo apt-get install dkms
>cd ~/build/rtl8821CU
>make
>sudo make install
# verified it had installed the driver this time
>ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8821cu
elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir
5.15.0-50-generic
```

Restarted my machine.
Wifi Networks showed up and everything works now.

oh and i had to

```
>sudo apt-get install linux-headers-${uname -r}
```

I have tried to replace the drivers following other posts suggestions and when that didn't work and since I'm only setting it up I just wiped everything and tried a fresh install again. The problem still persisted however.
I have tried following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPfLVsyQU_A) and everything installs fine without issue this time but when I reach iwcongif I get this:
[image]

Some other info that might be useful(I hope) to anyone that can help
[image]

[image]

[image]